# Uipath Range does not exist

Tags: excel, range, cell, uipath

I have created a simple **Write Cell** task, but I get an error that the range does not exist even if it clearly exists. What could be the problem?

[image: table]

[image: UiPath]

The formula I am using is:

`"=IF(AND((A2+B2)/2>70; OR(C2=""accepted""; D2=""accepted"")); ""accepted""; ""rejected"")"`

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Source: Write Cell
Message: The range does not exist
Exception Type: UiPath.Excel.ExcelException

Answer (score 0):

In your case you may get that error for

1) having the wrong formula in write cell. (I tried the following and it works)

[image]

```
"=IF(AND((A2+B2)/2 > 70,OR(C2=""accepted"",D2=""accepted"")), ""accepted"", ""rejected"")"
```

2) having your excel file open when you run the robot.